# cakePHP 1.2 no errors, no data received by browser

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I've got a site running with about 20 subdomains for a Non profit organisation. The subdomain is used as a key in the CMS query and all are relatively simple. Suddenly, after 6+ years, one of those subdomains won't load it's home page or inner pages.

Focussing on the homepage, in debug mode, I can see that I get as far as View::renderLayout

```
debug('sending to _render');
$out = View::_render($layoutFilename, $dataForLayout, $loadHelpers, true);
debug('back from _render');
```

My initial thought was that for some reason this subdomain had bloated data but a quick check showed it was the same size as the other subdomains.

If I put a marker into `View::_render` and it gets right to the end where it should

```
return $out;
```

I've debugged `$out` and it looks good but the "back from render" debug never gets run.

I don't normally wade through the source files but this is just so bizarre I expected to find at some stage an anomaly between the failing subdomain and the good ones. Or I'd expect different subdomains to fail randomly if it was a memory problem.

Looking through the SQL dump all the queries are consistent with the other subdomains.

Any ideas?

Comment: the problematic subdomain is still using the same source code as other subdomains?

Comment: Yes, the subdomains are "virtual" and all pointed to the www. The app controller's constructClasses would then work out which subdomain and add the key info to the object and make sure the right layout was used.

Comment: I do not think it is the core lib's problem since other subdomains are working. so probably you want to double check your application design and db values.

Comment: I've added a new method to one of the controllers that does nothing but the view says "hello". So all that gets run is a model load and the constructClasses that decides which subdomain is running and loads some basic info. Nothing has changed in the database for this subdomain in over 12 months.